# как вывести юзеров в мейн которые присутвуют в обьекте User и как отбросить исключение если их нет в данном обьекте?

Tags: java, исключения

У меня есть методы getUsers, getUserByLoginAndPassword, getUsersList
И нужно проверить если юзер не присутствует в созданном объекте то выбросить исключение

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UserNotFoundException, AccessDeniedException{
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Введите логин: ");
        String login = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Введите пароль: ");
        String password = scanner.nextLine();

        //TODO Проверить логин и пароль

        //TODO Вызвать методы валидации пользователя

        System.out.println();
        //System.out.println("Доступ представлен");
    }

    public static User[] getUsers(){
        User user1 = new User("john", "john@gmail.com", "pass", 24);
        User user2 = new User("john", "john@gmail.com", "pass", 22);
        User user3 = new User("john", "john@gmail.com", "pass", 24);
        return new User[]{user1, user2, user3};
    }

    public static User getUserByLoginAndPassword(String login, String password) throws UserNotFoundException{
        User[] users = getUsersList();
        for (User user : users) {


        }
        throw new UserNotFoundException("User not found");
    }

    private static User[] getUsersList() {
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Могу предложить такое решение, не самое красивое, но задачу решает.
Создал конструктор User. И в цикле

```
for (User user : users)
```

Проверяем на эквивалентность элементы и если совпадают то выкидываем Исключение. Предварительно расширяем класс Exception нашей реализацией.

```
import java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException;
import java.util.Scanner;

class User {
String name;
String login;
String pass;
Integer password;

public String getLogin() {
    return login;
}

public Integer getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public User(String name, String login, String pass, Integer password) {
    this.name = name;
    this.login = login;
    this.pass = pass;
    this.password = password;
}
static class UserNotFoundException extends Exception {
    public UserNotFoundException(String message) {
        super(message);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws UserNotFoundException, AccessDeniedException {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Введите логин: ");
            String login = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Введите пароль: ");
            String password = scanner.nextLine();
            User[] users = getUsers();
            getUserByLoginAndPassword(login, password);
            //TODO Проверить логин и пароль

            //TODO Вызвать методы валидации пользователя

            System.out.println();
            //System.out.println("Доступ представлен");
        }

        public static User[] getUsers() {
            User user1 = new User("john", "john@gmail.com", "pass", 24);
            User user2 = new User("john", "john@gmail.com", "pass", 22);
            User user3 = new User("john", "john@gmail.com", "pass", 24);
            return new User[]{user1, user2, user3};
        }

        public static User getUserByLoginAndPassword(String login, String password) throws UserNotFoundException {
            User[] users = getUsersList();
            boolean check = false;
            User temp = null;
            for (User user : users) {
            if (user.getLogin().toString().equals(login)
                        && user.getPassword().toString().equals(password)){
                    temp = user;
                    check = true;
                }
            }
            if (!check) {
                throw new UserNotFoundException("User not found");
            }
          return temp;
        }

        private static User[] getUsersList() {
        return getUsers();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо за решение, не обычное кнч, но я сделал так

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UserNotFoundException, AccessDeniedException{
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Введите логин: ");
        String login = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Введите пароль: ");
        String password = scanner.nextLine();

        //TODO Проверить логин и пароль

        //TODO Вызвать методы валидации пользователя
        User user = getUserByLoginAndPassword(login, password);
        System.out.println("User: " + user.getLogin() + " - " + user.getEmail());
        System.out.println("Access granted");



    }


    public static User[] getUsers(){
        User user1 = new User("john", "john@gmail.com", "pass", 24);
        User user2 = new User("mike", "mike@gmail.com", "qwerty", 22);
        User user3 = new User("steve", "steve@gmail.com", "asdfg", 23);
        return new User[]{user1, user2, user3};
    }

    public static User getUserByLoginAndPassword(String login, String password) throws UserNotFoundException{
        User[] users = getUsersList();
        for (User user : users) {
            if(login.equals(user.getLogin()) && password.equals(user.getPassword())){
                return user;
            }
        }
        throw new UserNotFoundException("User not found: " + login);
    }

    private static User[] getUsersList() {
        return getUsers();
    }
```